# sorting the pandas dataframe with two date-time columns on similar primary key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Initial dataframe looks like :

```
Primary Key     date_1        date_2
   22         2021-11-20      NaN
   22         2021-11-24      NaN
   22         NaN             2021-11-23
   22         NaN             2021-11-22
```

Desired Dataframe is :

```
  Primary Key   date_1        date_2
   22         2021-11-20      NaN
   22         NaN             2021-11-22
   22         NaN             2021-11-23
   22         2021-11-24      NaN
```

trying to sort on the basis of date column

```
df.sort_values(['Primary Key', 'date_1', 'date_2'],inplace=True) #how to approach sorting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `fillna` operation to combine your columns into a single `Series`, sort that `Series` and then use its index to re-order your original `DataFrame`:

```py
out = df.reindex(
    df['date_1'].fillna(df['date_2'])
    .sort_values().index
)

print(out)
   Primary Key      date_1      date_2
0           22  2021-11-20         NaN
3           22         NaN  2021-11-22
2           22         NaN  2021-11-23
1           22  2021-11-24         NaN
```

---

If you have a concern about your `Index`, you can also use `.reset_index` and `.iloc` to perform this sorting

```py
df = df.set_index('Primary Key')

indices = (
    df['date_1'].fillna(df['date_2'])
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .sort_values().index
)

out = df.iloc[indices]
print(out)
                 date_1      date_2
Primary Key                        
22           2021-11-20         NaN
22                  NaN  2021-11-22
22                  NaN  2021-11-23
22           2021-11-24         NaN
```

Comment: is this approach suitable for the dataframe with multiple "Primary Key"...?

Comment: Is the `primary key` the Index of the dataframe? Or is it a column of the DataFrame?

Comment: it is the column of the dataframe

Comment: Then this approach should work perfectly well with your data :)

Comment: its working..!!! kudos :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way - you basically take the flat list of two columns and argsort to get the indexes but take only the first four after normalizing the values to the length of the dataframe.

```
idx = (np.argsort(np.ravel([df['date_1'], df['date_2']])) % len(df))[:len(df)]
out = df.loc[idx]
```

print(out):

```
   Primary Key     date_1     date_2
0           22 2021-11-20        NaT
3           22        NaT 2021-11-22
2           22        NaT 2021-11-23
1           22 2021-11-24        NaT
```